# R: assigning patients to new and followup based on date

Tags: r

to all R experts..

I have a  data set of 60000 entries of cardiovascular diseases(CVD) in an area. The data is  mainly  consisting of: patient number, date that he came to the health centre and many other variables like his village, his health centre etc..

Based on a definition that each patient is allowed only one visit during a year, I want to apply that to the data set. That is, I want to assign beside each patient if this visit is new ( a first visit during a year) or follow up ( a repeated visit in a year). this is my str() of the data.

```
> str(cvd1)
'data.frame':   59686 obs. of  51 variables:
 $ Age           : num  3532642 3555351 3575931 3599113 3622295 ...
 $ Centre        : Factor w/ 8 levels "L","M","N","SH",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Date          : Date, format: "2006-11-21" ...
 $ DoB           : Date, format: "1966-01-01" ...

  $ Ptnum          : Factor w/ 7469 levels "5011","5057",..: 4398 2105 2105 2105 2105 4352 1304 1304 1304 1304 ...
  $ Sex           : Factor w/ 3 levels "F","M","UNKNOWN": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
```

this is just an example to illustrate what I want to do:

```
list = 1:8
Ptnum = c(1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3)
date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2000","24/02/2000", "26/03/2006", "04/05/2001",
"05/05/2007","05/05/2001","05/05/2007")
cvddata = data.frame(Ptnum, date)
```

formatting dates as R date object

```
 cvddata$date = dmy(date)
```

so, Ptnum(1), the first visit is new case, the 3rd visit of ptnum(1) is(follow up,,coming within a year). the  5th visit of ptnum(1)is( new, coming after a year of his first) but his 7th visit is ( follow up, because he came within a year from the last one, which is 04/05/2001).

thank you

Comment: You need to format those dates as R Date class vectors, then sort by pt id and date and then use `ave` (grouping by id) using a function that compares adjacent dates. Left ambiguous (by you) is what is needed, for example, there were a string of 5 visits each separated by 6 months.

Comment: Dear DWin,
The date is formatted as.date..in the str(cvd1)..
would you please further explain your point regarding the date.. I'm a beginner in R..

thats fine I just did that..

Comment: The "date" column in your example are _not_ R dates. Read `as.Date` and `ISOdate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where `dmy` comes from. I would do it with `as.Date`:

```
Ptnum = c(1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3)
date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2000","24/02/2000", "26/03/2006", "04/05/2001",
"05/05/2007","05/05/2001","05/05/2007")
cvddata = data.frame(Ptnum, date)
cvddata$date = as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
cvddat.ord$new1yr <- with(cvddat.ord, 
                        ave(as.numeric(date), Ptnum, 
                                  FUN=function(x) c(1000, diff(x) ) > 365) )
cvddat.ord
 #---------------
  Ptnum       date new1yr
1     1 2000-01-01      1
3     1 2000-02-24      0
5     1 2001-05-04      1
7     1 2001-05-05      0
2     2 2000-01-01      1
6     2 2007-05-05      1
8     3 2007-05-05      1
4     4 2006-03-26      1
```

Comment: Thank you very very much ...
I can even change the follow up period from 365 to the days I want..thank you again..

Comment: Hey!  What about leap year!  :-)

Comment: That is a good point,,However, I don't think it will affect my results if I did not consider it..thank you :)